# mean encoding, polars vs pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I'm trying to optimize pandas mean encoding calculation using polars, however the performance turns out to be slower, is this the correct way how to perform mean encoding in polars?

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10069612 entries, 0 to 10069611
Data columns (total 26 columns):
dtypes: float64(1), int16(2), int8(15), object(8)
memory usage: 873.9+ MB


%timeit df["product_avg_sales"] = df.groupby("product")["sales"].transform("mean")
219 ms ± 7.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


df_polar = pl.from_pandas(df)
%timeit df_polar.with_columns(pl.col('sales').mean().over(['product']).alias('product_avg_sales'))
1.19 s ± 24.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: You haven't shared example of your data. But if you cast your data types to a less memory consuming formats, you will improve performance. For instance, column `product` looks to be categorical, so you can cast it to `pl.Categorical`.

Comment: Could you add an example that shows this numbers? We could not reproduce it. See thread on github: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5037